# Bitbucket NPM private package not install dependencies

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

I have my own NPM package in bitbucket as private repository which I installed in my main project as following:

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "my-package": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/{name}/my-package.git"
    }
```

This works like a charm, but there's a problem with the package itself. It contains a package.json with its own dependencies, but my main NPM is not installing this, it does not seem to keep in consideration what my package's package.json contains.

E.g: I am now missing packages that my own packages requires.

What can I do to make NPM always install my package packages defined in package.json?

Structure wise:

```
MyApp
   - package.json (I run npm install on this one)
   - some other php files..
   - node_modules
      - my-package
         - package.json <-- This contains dependencies, which are not installed
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, problem was that we defined our packages in the devDependencies, which should be in the dependencies.